# Query reg SMTP port

Tags: email, smtp

Hi am having a confusion reg SMTP ports. I have configured an application in my local machine to use gmail's smtp server by getting the details from here - https://www.siteground.com/kb/google_free_smtp_server/ and am able to trigger emails without any issues. 
When I set the same application in a windows server and use the same smtp settings the emails aren't going and I keep getting errors like "unable to connect to smtp port 465".  So is the port being mentioned here - 465 - is this port being used from my machine to connect to gmail's smtp server or is this port being referred to the port in the machine where gmail's smtp server is hosted?

Comment: 465 is a standard SSL port for for SMTP as described in the document you have linked, this means it is the servers port, and has nothing to do with your local socket port allocated randomly by the system to the establishing connection, which is always a much higher number.

Comment: Is there any way I could find out which port was used locally to establish the connection. Windows or Linux anything is fine.

Comment: Programmatically or with tool? Netstat is one option on windows...

Comment: Thank you will try out netstat.